# Ajax.ActionLink in MVC3 is getting slow after a number of requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this simple MVC 3 application which simply has two controllers(Home and Edit), two actions one per controller and two views for each action,

each one of the views has an ajax action link which simply request the other view and displays the result in a div, the problem is that after a certain number of requests the page is getting slower, I checked that with fiddler and noticed that each time I press the action link the request will be send multiple times according to the equation (2 to the power n) where n is how many time the link was pressed, find below the controllers and views.

**the Controllers**

```
public class EditController : Controller
{       
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}


    public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Text = "Home Page";
        return View();
    }
}
```

**And the views**

**Home View**

```
  @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    }
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myCallback(xhr, status) {
            alert(status);
        } 
    </script>
    <div id="divLoading" style="display: none">
        Loading ...</div>
    <div id="divResultText">
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit Ajax", "Index", "Edit", null, new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "Get",
        OnComplete = "myCallback",
        UpdateTargetId = "divResultText",
        LoadingElementId = "divLoading"
    })
    </div>
```

**Edit View**

```
   @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    }
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "Get",
        UpdateTargetId = "divResultText",
        LoadingElementId = "divLoading"
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer in

[Ajax.ActionLink in MVC3 is getting slow after a number of requests](http://forums.asp.net/post/4725770.aspx)